# Copying from A1 into range B1:B5 and doing same for the rest An cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a home work to do.. it's about copying A1 cell into range B1:B5 and doing the same for the other A2 into range B6:B11

The code was

```
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("B1:B5")
Range("A2").Copy Destination:=Range("B6:B11")
Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Range("B12:B17")
```

and so on.. I have 100 text in A cell, so I can't run it manually one by one

I want to run the vba automatically, I've tried to search, but I got nothing.

Comment: As it's "home work", be careful not to be done for **plagairism** particularly if the answer uses concepts not covered by your course material.

Comment: Hi Mark, its not a formal home work, just a usual home work for my kind job.

Comment: The B ranges have different numbers of elements.  The first has 4 and the second two has 5.  Without consistency automation will be difficult or impossible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub copyTest()
Range("b:b").Clear
Range("b1:b5") = Range("a1")
Range("a2").Select
While ActiveCell <> ""
Range(Cells(Range("b1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, 2), _
Cells(Range("b1000").End(xlUp).Offset(6, 0).Row, 2)) = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this good for you?

```
Sub Test()
  Dim R1 As Integer, R2 As Integer
  For R1 = 1 To 10
    R2 = R1 * 5 - 4
    Range("A" & R1).Copy Destination:=Range("B" & R2 & ":B" & R2 + 4)
  Next R1
End Sub
```

Comment: The first copy must go into 5 cells, the second copy must go into 6 cells.

Comment: This code is also work but only from range A1 to A10.. but thank you for your kind reply..